# Получение данных с датчиков Verve2 с помощью python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется набор Verve2. Данные обрабатываются в поставляемом приложении, но действия ограничены и только через "родное" приложение - имитировать нажатие какой-то клавиши или отправить сообщение. Хочется найти способ получать данные "напрямую" и иметь возможность использовать их в своем коде.

Answer (score 0):

Может немного реверс инжиниринга?

В диспечере устройств посмотри формат порта usb-com или просто usb?

Потом доставай wireshark https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB, открывай порт и крути ручки.

Как станет понятно как кодируются данные переходи к питону.

Там либо через libusb (https://libusb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) открываешь нужные эндпоинты и начинаешь читать.

Или через pyserial (https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html) открываешь порт и получаешь поток байт.

Обрати внимание есть ли загрузка прошивки при подключении устройства.

Comment: А несколько подробней можно? Как, к примеру,разобраться с Wireshark?